Inequality with distribution and integral
Let $a \in (0,1)$ be the (unique) solution of:
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 (\theta - a)e^{\dfrac{(\theta - a)^2}{\beta}}g(\theta)d\theta = 0$ (1), where $g(\theta)$ is a continuously differentiable probability distribution i.e. $\displaystyle \int_0^1 g(\theta)d\theta = 1$, $g'(\theta)$ is continuous, and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \theta g(\theta)d\theta \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$ (2), where $\beta \in R^{+}$ (3).
The condition (2) literally means that when $\beta \rightarrow \infty$, the solution $a$ in (1) lies in $[\frac{1}{2},1)$. If the integral in (2) is less than $\frac{1}{2}$, the inequality (a) will be reversed.
Show that:
a. $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq  a \leq \displaystyle \int_0^1 \theta g(\theta)d\theta$, or find a counter-example for it.
b. Verify the monotonicity of $a$ when $\beta$ varies, i.e. $a$ increases when $\beta $ increases, and vice versa.
My attempt:
The probably simplest case is when $g(\theta)$ is a uniform distribution, then $a = 1/2$ that satisfies (a).
Update******
So far, in  (a),  I can prove $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq  a$ if $g(\theta)$ is monotonic (i.e. decreasing or increasing) but not for the remaining part, $a \leq \displaystyle \int_0^1 \theta g(\theta)d\theta$.
Following is the scratch of the proof when $g$ is increasing.
Consider $h(a) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (\theta - a)e^{\dfrac{(\theta - a)^2}{\beta}}g(\theta)d\theta$, then $h'(a) = - \displaystyle \int_0^1 (1 + \dfrac{2(\theta - a)^2}{\beta})e^{\dfrac{(\theta - a)^2}{\beta}}g(\theta)d\theta < 0$.
Next step I am gonna show that $h(\dfrac{1}{2}) > 0$:
$h(\dfrac{1}{2}) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (\theta - \dfrac{1}{2})e^{\dfrac{(\theta - \dfrac{1}{2})^2}{\beta}}g(\theta)d\theta$.
We do this by employing the Chebyshev inequality for two increasing functions:
$(\theta - \dfrac{1}{2})e^{\dfrac{(\theta - \dfrac{1}{2})^2}{\beta}}$ and $g(\theta)$:
$h(\dfrac{1}{2}) \geq \displaystyle \int_0^1 (\theta - \dfrac{1}{2})e^{\dfrac{(\theta - \dfrac{1}{2})^2}{\beta}}d\theta  \displaystyle \int_0^1 g(\theta)d\theta = 0$, thus $a \geq \frac{1}{2}$, since $h(a) = 0$.
But I got stuck while proving $a \leq \displaystyle \int_0^1 \theta g(\theta)d\theta $ when $g$ is increasing.
For the general case of $g$ (not necessarily monotonic), I have tested its correctness when $g(.)$ is normal distribution, uniform distribution, and beta distribution using MATLAB, but failed to produce a formal proof for it.
To show the monotonicity in (b), the Implicit theorem implies:
$\dfrac{da}{d\beta} = \dfrac{\dfrac{-\partial h}{\partial \beta}}{\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial a}}$, here I abuse the notation for the function $h$ with respect to $\theta$.
As $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial a} < 0 $ for all $\beta$, it boils down to show that:
$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial \beta} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (\theta - a)^3 e^{\dfrac{(\theta - a)^2}{\beta}}g(\theta)d\theta < 0 (*)$, if conditions (1),(2) and (3) are met.
However, the inequality (*) is unexpectedly hard, so I haven't made any progress on it.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help.
